# Re-Construct a png image from a GDK Pixbuf

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, gdkpixbuf, bytesio

I want to send an image Pixbuf over a socket but the received image is only in black and white and distorted.
Here are the steps I'm using:

1) get pixels array of that Pixbuf

2) serialize the pixels array

3) Convert the serialized string to a BytesIO

4) Send over the socket

```
MyShot = ScreenShot2()
frame = MyShot.GetScreenShot() #this function returns the Pixbuf
a = frame.get_pixels_array()
Sframe = pickle.dumps( a, 1)
b = BytesIO()
b.write(Sframe)
b.seek(0)
```

after this I have to rebuild the image by:

1) Deserialize the received string in its original pixels array

2) Build the Pixbuf from the pixels array

3) Save the image

```
res = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_data(pickle.loads(b.getvalue()), frame.get_colorspace(), False, frame.get_bits_per_sample(), frame.get_width(), frame.get_height(), frame.get_rowstride()) #also tried this res = gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_array(pickle.loads(b.read()),gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB,8)
res.save("result.png","png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a `Pixbuf` over a socket you have to send *all* data, not just the pixels.  The `BytesIO` object is not necessary as Numpy arrays have a `tostring()` method.

It would be easier/make more sense to send a PNG instead of sending raw data and encode it at the receiving end to a PNG image.  Here a `BytesIO` object actually is necessary to avoid a temporary file.  Sending side:

```
screen = ScreenShot()
image = screen.get_screenshot()
png_file = BytesIO()
image.save_to_callback(png_file.write)
data = png_file.getvalue()
```

Then send `data` over the socket and on the receiving side simply save it:

```
with open('result.png', 'wb') as png_file:
    png_file.write(data)
```